# Empty url in urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a project with several views e.g. - index, contacts and about.
And I want `url www.aaa.net` links to index view, `www.aaa.net/about` to about view and so on
In project urls.py I wrote

```
url(r'^$', include('mysite.urls'))
```

In app urls.py I wrote

```
url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
url(r'about/$',views.about,name='about'),
url(r'contacts/$',views.contacts,name='contacts'),
```

But it works only with index view, about and contacts didn't work at all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `$` at the end of

```
url(r'^$', include('mysite.urls'))
```

When you are trying to include, `$`, in the regex match implies the end of the url pattern, which was the cause of the issue.

You are probably looking for

```
url(r'^', include('mysite.urls'))
```

More info on including URL patterns [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs)