# Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name - Django App

Tags: python, django

I am getting the above error in my django app it was working fine earlier. I can't figure out the error after 2 hours.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
  return render(request,'dashboard/index.html')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
 from . import views

 urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
 ]
```

**dashboard/index.html**
Here is the template page.which i am using in dashboard app

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}
<div class="dash_home">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
{% endblock%}
```

**Traceback**

Here is the full trace back of my app. I removed most of the code but i am still getting this error. I am new to django please help me

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/dashboard/

Template error:
In template 
C:\Users\devst\Desktop\django\miniproject\templates\cryptopedia\layout.html, 
error at line 0
   Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern 
name.
   1 : {% load staticfiles %}
   2 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   3 : <html lang="en">
   4 : <head>
   5 :   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   6 :   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
scale=1.0">
   7 :   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   8 :   <title>CryptoPedia</title>
   9 :   <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
   10 :    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">


Traceback:
File "C:\Users\devst\Desktop\django\miniproject\dashboard\views.py" in index
  8.     return render(request,'dashboard/index.html')

File "C:\Users\devst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, 
using=using)

File "C:\Users\devst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "C:\Users\devst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\devst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  175.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\devst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\devst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\devst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\devst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\devst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\devst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)


File "C:\Users\devst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site - 
packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  632.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /dashboard/
Exception Value: Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function 
or pattern name.
```

Comment: add the full traceback

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Empty url in urls.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601751/empty-url-in-urls-py)

Comment: add the template `dashboard/index.html`

Comment: No I don't think that's the problem

Comment: I m asking you to add that template in your question

Comment: anyone? please Help

Comment: Do you see this when you hit `http://server/` or when you hit `http://server/dashboard/`?

Comment: Yes exactly? Do you know the reason?